# Rigify - arm twist troubles (pose/rest - IK> FK)

Tags: animation, armature, rigify

I have problem with arm tweaks. I noticed this problem when creating animation and try snap IK to FK. After snapping I have [this](https://streamable.com/dll0ga). Then I was advised to change A or T pose, but this did not solve the problem.

I started to understand the topic and found these basic rigs:

- [Quadruped](https://streamable.com/yp4ga9) Meta-Rig
- [Human](https://streamable.com/80mgav) Meta-Rig

With Bird and Cat; Meta-Rig all ok, twist is good. But with Horse and Wolf I have the same problem as above.
I don't know if this is a bug or something else. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I need help with that :)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the red IK control for the hand. Press N, to get the property panel on ITEM tab. Scroll to "Toggle Pole", set it to 1. Align this new orientation control.
Your problem is a point-to-target issue with the controlled direction from this Toggle Pole control.
To match IK - FK slides, you can use the MAGNETO ICON that says Fk-Ik to match it so to that position from FK to IK (FK are the green controllers, IK are the red controls)

[image]